# How do i return all elements in while loop?

Tags: php, database, function, pdo

I have a function which grabs logs from database, but whenever im trying to echo this. I am only getting first item.

```
        function getCoins($odb) {
        $website = new website();
        $SQLGetCoinsLog = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `user_logs` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
        while ($getInfo = $SQLGetCoinsLog -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
            $id = $getInfo['id'];
            $userid = $getInfo['userid'];
            $nazwa = $getInfo['nazwa'];
            $cena = $getInfo['cena'];
            $transid = $getInfo['transid'];
            $data = $website->converTimestamp($getInfo['data']);
            $result = '
                <tr class="text-center">
                    <td><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$userid.'" target="_blank">'.$userid.'</a></td>
                    <td>'.$nazwa.'</td>
                    <td>'.$cena.'PLN</td>
                    <td>'.$transid.'</td>
                    <td>'.$data.'</td>
                </tr>                                           
            ';
        }
        return $result;
        }
```

Comment: Either you echo the result in the loop or you create an array with all the results and echo them later

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
$result = "";
```

At the top of your function to define it (before the while loop), then change your

```
$result = ' <tr class="text-center"> <td><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$userid.'" target="_blank">'.$userid.'</a></td> <td>'.$nazwa.'</td> <td>'.$cena.'PLN</td> <td>'.$transid.'</td> <td>'.$data.'</td> </tr> ';
```

To

```
$result .= ' <tr class="text-center"> <td><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$userid.'" target="_blank">'.$userid.'</a></td> <td>'.$nazwa.'</td> <td>'.$cena.'PLN</td> <td>'.$transid.'</td> <td>'.$data.'</td> </tr> ';
```

Note the dot next to equals, this will add to and not overwrite your variable.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options.
Echo them in the loop (that does not "return" them) so that really doesn't answer your question, but since it's a table you build, at some point I assume it has to be echoed.

```
   function getCoins($odb) {
    $website = new website();
    $SQLGetCoinsLog = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `user_logs` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    while ($getInfo = $SQLGetCoinsLog -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $getInfo['id'];
        $userid = $getInfo['userid'];
        $nazwa = $getInfo['nazwa'];
        $cena = $getInfo['cena'];
        $transid = $getInfo['transid'];
        $data = $website->converTimestamp($getInfo['data']);
        echo'
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$userid.'" target="_blank">'.$userid.'</a></td>
                <td>'.$nazwa.'</td>
                <td>'.$cena.'PLN</td>
                <td>'.$transid.'</td>
                <td>'.$data.'</td>
            </tr>                                           
        ';
    }
    }
```

Or you can build an array with the results:

```
   function getCoins($odb) {
    $website = new website();
    $SQLGetCoinsLog = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `user_logs` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    while ($getInfo = $SQLGetCoinsLog -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $getInfo['id'];
        $userid = $getInfo['userid'];
        $nazwa = $getInfo['nazwa'];
        $cena = $getInfo['cena'];
        $transid = $getInfo['transid'];
        $data = $website->converTimestamp($getInfo['data']);
        $result[] = '
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$userid.'" target="_blank">'.$userid.'</a></td>
                <td>'.$nazwa.'</td>
                <td>'.$cena.'PLN</td>
                <td>'.$transid.'</td>
                <td>'.$data.'</td>
            </tr>                                           
        ';
    }
    return $result;
    }

//To echo them in main program:
Echo implode("\n", getCoins($odb));
```

Or you can build a string with all the results:

```
    function getCoins($odb) {
    $website = new website();
    $SQLGetCoinsLog = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `user_logs` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $result = "";
    while ($getInfo = $SQLGetCoinsLog -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $getInfo['id'];
        $userid = $getInfo['userid'];
        $nazwa = $getInfo['nazwa'];
        $cena = $getInfo['cena'];
        $transid = $getInfo['transid'];
        $data = $website->converTimestamp($getInfo['data']);
        $result .= '
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$userid.'" target="_blank">'.$userid.'</a></td>
                <td>'.$nazwa.'</td>
                <td>'.$cena.'PLN</td>
                <td>'.$transid.'</td>
                <td>'.$data.'</td>
            </tr>                                           
        ';
    }
    return $result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These variables which you gave the database row's results isn't useful or you cannot benifit them because all of them are `local variables` or they're deleted and recreated after loop repeated because you created them in the loop, you should create them outside the loop, (e.g.) i think you just need the result so i just add the result outside the loop:-

```
function getCoins($odb) {
    $website = new website();
    $SQLGetCoinsLog = $odb -> query("SELECT * FROM `user_logs` ORDER BY `id` DESC");
    $result = array();
    while ($getInfo = $SQLGetCoinsLog -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        $id = $getInfo['id'];
        $userid = $getInfo['userid'];
        $nazwa = $getInfo['nazwa'];
        $cena = $getInfo['cena'];
        $transid = $getInfo['transid'];
        $data = $website->converTimestamp($getInfo['data']);
        array_push($result, '
            <tr class="text-center">
                <td><a href="https://steamcommunity.com/profiles/'.$userid.'" target="_blank">'.$userid.'</a></td>
                <td>'.$nazwa.'</td>
                <td>'.$cena.'PLN</td>
                <td>'.$transid.'</td>
                <td>'.$data.'</td>
            </tr>                                           
        ');
    }
    return $result;
    }
```